# Superagent share session / cookie info with actual browser

Tags: node.js, session, cookies, request, superagent

I create a program so that i can test my backend API server /login functionality.  I send requests to the server using superagent and everything works fine except the login session has nothing to do with my actual browser login session.

When I POST to /login I will get a response header with a field 'Set-Cookie' that tells me to set cookie value.  When this cookie I can stay loggedin with the backend server.  But apparently superagent didn't set the cookie value for me although POST /login is successful.

So how do I share the session/cookie info with browser?

```
var request = require('superagent');

request.post('http://localhost:3000/login')
  .send({email: 'test@gmail.com', password: 'test@gmail.com'})
  .end(function(err, res){
    console.log(err)
    console.log(res.header)
  })
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming that you're making this request from an origin other than `localhost:3000`, otherwise the browser should already be sending the cookies for the request.

Superagent uses the `XMLHttpRequest` object in the browser to make http requests.  By default, [cross-origin requests do not send cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Requests_with_credentials).  In order to get `XMLHttpRequest` to send cookies/authentication headers, you must set the `withCredentials` property of the request to `true`.  Superagent [makes this easy](https://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/#cors).  Just use the `.withCredentials()` method on your request:

```
var request = require('superagent');

request.post('http://localhost:3000/login')
  .send({email: 'test@gmail.com', password: 'test@gmail.com'})
  .withCredentials()
  .end(function(err, res){
    console.log(err)
    console.log(res.header)
  })
```

Comment: I guess withCredentials() is not es6 compatible right?